# How to link Wayland header files in C?

Tags: c, wayland

I am starting out with coding for Wayland. I have been following many tutorials, but I am still stuck at compiling. I wrote this very simple code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<wayland-client-core.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct wl_display *display = wl_display_connect(NULL);
    if(!display) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to Wayland display\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Connection established!\n");
    getchar();
    wl_display_disconnect(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I tried to compile it with `gcc -o client -lwayland-client client.c`
But, compilation fails with this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfXeOS8.o: in function `main':
client.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `wl_display_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: client.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `wl_display_disconnect'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This looks strange because there is a file `/usr/include/wayland-client-core.h` in the system, which has got these declarations:

```c
struct wl_display *wl_display_connect(const char *name);
void wl_display_disconnect(struct wl_display *display);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not `#include <wayland-client.h>`

Comment: @i486 that's because `wayland-client.h` file says `\warning Use of this header file is discouraged. Prefer including
 *  wayland-client-core.h instead, which does not include the
 *  client protocol header and as such only defines the library
 *  API.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the command line to:

```
gcc client.c -o client -lwayland-client
```

or:

```
gcc client.c -lwayland-client -o client
```

or:

```
gcc -o client client.c -lwayland-client
```

Basically, the .c file (or .o file) needs to appear before the library linking options.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am linking external libraries from the terminal for the first time and I didn't know that the order of arguments also matters.

Answer (score 2):

It matters because the linker looks in the library for any un-resolved symbols. If there are no unresolved symbols when it gets to the library then it has nothing to look for.
Another thing, in general when you are using a non-standard library you have to tell the linker how to find the library. You do this with the -L option (upper case as opposed to lowercase). You can have several -L options pointing to several different directories e.g. -L. (the current directory) -L../include (the include directory in the parent of the current directory) etc.